# Android Adding Search Functionality to ListView

Tags: android, search, android-activity, android-edittext

following this tutorial : [tuto](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

I want to make a search functionnality with an EditText into my ListActivity.

This tutorial explains how to do it but using a simple ArrayAdapter :

```
// Listview Data
    String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                            "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                            "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

I would to be able to make it too but with my custom: ArrayAdapter

Edit :

It's now working find with the toString() returned value of my object.

Now I have this problem:

In my EditText I have "wine" and on my List I have just one element containing this word:
my list:

```
-----------------
---------
The god of wine and orange juice
---------------
----------------------
```

It's fine working and I now just have "The god.." on result but if I put a space after wine the result will disappear..

Comment: Answered [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268592/1531054)

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever you want in to the `ArrayAdapter`, ie...`ArrayAdapter<MyObject>`, just override the `toString()` method within your model class to set what will display within the list.